# How to access Doctrine inside a PHP package?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm creating a PHP package that will reside in the `/vendor` directory and it needs to access the database using Doctrine.  In my main Symfony 4.2 code, I can access the database by using autowiring in the constructors like this:

```
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
```

However, this only works with Symfony and does not seem to work inside public bundles.  Please note that I need to access the default database connection, I do not want to create a new connection if one already exists.

I am trying to create a package that will work both with and without Symfony, so what I really need is the raw PHP to get the current database connection (not a new connection) without all the autowiring magic.

If the package is running under Symfony, it should use the current Symfony database connection.  If not, it should create its own connection.

For example, I can open a new connection like this:

```
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($params, $config)
```

That works fine, but I need a way to get the current Symfony database connection (something like this):

```
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getCurrentConnection()
```

Unfortunately, there is no such function and I can't figure out how to create my own version of it.

Comment: I just found a good video tutorial that explains Symfony bundles and composer packages in great detail:

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-bundle/bundle-directory

I haven't figured everything out yet, but it is starting to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the class as a service and inject the EntityManager as an argument:

```
# vendor/Acme/HelloBundle/Resources/Config/services.yml

services:
    acme_hellp.service_id:
        class: Acme\HelloBundle\Class   
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

```
// src/Acme/HelloBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeHelloExtension.php

namespace Acme\HelloBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;

class AcmeHelloExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new XmlFileLoader(
           $container,
           new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
        );
        $loader->load('services.xml');
    }
}
```

Also, check this documentation on the Symfony site how to load your config files:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html

Comment: I've been looking at that section for over an hour and can't make sense of it (maybe because it's way past my normal bedtime).  Some actual working examples would be more helpful.

Comment: Well copied the code from the Symfony site for you.. 1. Add services.yml with the service definition 2. add load function in your bundle extension class to load services.yml

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I don't understand what I'm supposed to put in the config files.  There is too much magic going on with the autowiring stuff.

What is the raw PHP needed to get the current Doctrine entity manager?  If I had that, I could solve my problem.  I'm trying to create a package that will work both with and without Symfony.  If it is running under Symfony, it will get the current Symfony database connection.  If running outside Symfony, it will create its own database connection (that part is already working).

Comment: For example, I can open a new connection like this:
`$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($params, $config)`

What I really need is a way to get the current connection without all the autowiring stuff, something like this:
`$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getCurrentConnection()`

Unfortunately, no such function exists and I cannot figure out how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand your problem, are you looking for a package to share using the doctrine Entity Manager of Symfony? so let me share with you my experience.

That is possible, and there are no solution visible to read or watch, so you need to review some packages to understand how they resolve the problem, the package i review was on this [link](https://packagist.org/packages/mmucklo/queue-bundle), this package provide a support not only doctrine, also others platforms like Mongo, so let me share with you how they made the solution.

First, you need to crete a package in a bitbucket or github, and made this package as "type": "symfony-bundle". i read the comments before and you are correct, you need to create a Configuration and Extension file to enable you packages, so in your extension file you need to implement a **Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface** this package will allow you make the magic. so you can write some lines of code similar of this and replace for your namespace:

```php
<?php
namespace NameSpaceBundle\CoreBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

/**
 * Class NameSpaceBundleExtension Configurations of the Core
 * @package NameSpaceBundle\CoreBundle\DependencyInjection
 */
class NameSpaceBundleExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @param array $configs
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        $loader->load('routing.yml');
        $this->processConfiguration(new Configuration(), $configs);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configs = $container->getExtensionConfig($this->getAlias());
        $this->processConfiguration(new Configuration(), $configs);
        $doctrineConfig = [];
        $doctrineConfig['orm']['mappings'][] = array(
            'name' => 'NameSpaceBundle',
            'is_bundle' => true,
            'type' => 'annotation',
            'prefix' => 'NameSpaceBundle\CoreBundle\Entity'
        );
        $container->prependExtensionConfig('doctrine', $doctrineConfig);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'bundelName_core';
    }
}
```

Review your service.yaml allocated on Resouces/config and now you can inject not only EntityManagerInterface.

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: false      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: false # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    public: false

  NameSpaceBundle\CoreBundle\Manager\Company:
    public: false
    class: NameSpaceBundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\CompanyManager
    arguments:
      - '@doctrine'
      - '\NameSpaceBundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Company'
```

Also this aprouch is similar of some packages of FriendsOfSymfony and the package i tell you before.

PD. Sorry for my english is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

After a couple days of trying to create a Symfony bundle to make things work the "official" way, I figured out a one-liner hack that gets the Symfony Doctrine connection and does what I need.  It relies on the fact that `$kernel` is a Symfony global:

```
// Singleton to get Doctrine database connection
//
// If we are running on the legacy system, it will open a new database connection.
//
// If we are running under Symfony, it will use the existing Doctrine
// connection.

class Doctrine
{
     static private $instance = null;
     private $conn;

     // The database connection is established in a private constructor
     private function __construct()
     {
         global $kernel;

         if (class_exists('\config')) {
             // running on legacy system
             $cfg = new \config();

             //
             // set up Doctrine connection
             //
             $params = [
                 'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
                 'user'     => $cfg->db_username,
                 'password' => $cfg->db_password,
                 'host'     => $cfg->db_hostname,
                 'dbname'   => $cfg->db_name,
             ];
             $config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();

             $this->conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($params, $config);
         } else {
             // running on Symfony system
             $this->conn = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')->getConnection();
         }
     }

     static public function getInstance()
     {
         if (!self::$instance) {
             self::$instance = new Doctrine();
         }

         return self::$instance;
     }

     static public function connection()
     {
         return self::getInstance()->getConnection();
     }

     public function getConnection()
     {
         return $this->conn;
     }
 }
```

By using the above class, this simple statement will get a Doctrine connection in both Symfony and our legacy code:

```
$conn = Doctrine::connection()
```

Now we can the same libraries on both Symfony and our legacy code.  Yes, I know it's a hack, but it is easier to understand and maintain than the 10+ files and dozens of lines of code required to create even a simple Symfony bundle (and the legacy system won't recognize a bundle).  I've put this class in a private composer package that can be used by both legacy systems and Symfony. This will make it much easier to keep things running until we can migrate all the legacy stuff to Symfony.  After that is done, then I can do things the right way.